Why does Blender freeze when compiling shaders
A lot of game engines and other software compile shaders in the background and show a placeholder shader (or the old shader) during compilation. Why doesn't Blender do this?
Sometimes I modify shader nodes and have to wait 10-20 seconds just because I unplugged something while editing

What answer do you expect? Computing needs time. It's faster with faster hardware. Certainly does not take 10-20 seconds with a decent GPU unless you have crazy procedural setups in your shaders in which case it's slow because it's complex. Baking helps. What's the point of this question?

I’m voting to close this question because it's not really about using Blender. Technical reasons why some algorithms work some ways are more related to the development of Blender, which is off-topic. Also the problem cannot be solved in an answer.
